# How to implement if one checkbox is selected then second checkbox will be auto selected?

Tags: vba

I have two checkboxes, chkbox1 and chkbox2. I want if chbox1 is selected then,chkbox2 will be auto selected and it's value should be 1.
How can i achieve this in visual basic code.Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should check the checkbox2 when you check checkbox1

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
CheckBox2.Value = False
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
CheckBox2.Value = True
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, checkbox2.value=checkbox1.value.